# unsigned short * and wchar_t error in C++

Tags: javascript, c++, c

I'm using VS2008 to make an C++ DLL for Fljs which is js used by Adobe Flash.

The hell function need an arg with type  of `unsigned short *` used for register function name in js.

I use the sample successfully do some simple operations in js.It pass the arg use `_T("functionname")`

But the sample is C code.When I use C++ code(just change the .c to .cpp), VS tell me `wchar_t` is inner type, so I turn the option off and now the `wchar_t` is typedef of unsigned short.

Then compile it without error.But in js , it can't find the function name.

So I want to know why the js can't find the name?
What had been done with the `wchar_t` which is both typedef of `unsigned short` in C and C++?

Comment: Probably the name iof the function got mangled, so you can find it as C function, but not as C++.

Comment: I saw the value is complete in VS debug.But the register function is define in Flash and Flash do the register,I don't know its implementation.

Comment: If the name is exported wrong then Flahs will not find it. In the debugger you don't see this because the debugger knows how to unmangle it. OYuo have to look into it with a tool that can show you the exported symbols. Try to see if you delare the function as C explizitly, if this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely your function names are now mangled if you switch to C++ and don't flag the exported functions as C style.

You can see an explanation here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ys435b3s.aspx#fbid=9ENgg2d3TwT)

What you can try is to make them C again.

```
extern "C" {  // only need to export C interface if

__declspec( dllimport ) void MyCFunc();

};
```

Comment: I had solved my problem!The Fljs just dosen't accpet C++ function to register by its register function.It dosen't need `__declspec( dllimport )`  to export function at all.But I use `extern "C"` for my C++ interface function so that I can call it in a C function which I can smoothly register.Thanks!